# error unclosed string literal

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

```
st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT venta.`Codigo_V` AS venta_Codigo_V, venta.`Total` AS venta_Total, 
     venta.`Fecha` AS venta_Fecha, detalle_venta.`Codigo_V` AS detalle_venta_Codigo_V, 
     detalle_venta.`Codigo_P` AS detalle_venta_Codigo_P, detalle_venta.`Precio` AS detalle_venta_Precio, 
     detalle_venta.`Cantidad` AS detalle_venta_Cantidad, detalle_venta.`Descuento` AS detalle_venta_Descuento, 
     detalle_venta.`SubTotal` AS detalle_venta_SubTotal, producto.`Codigo_P` AS producto_Codigo_P, 
     producto.`Descripcion_P` AS producto_Descripcion_P, producto.`Precio_P` AS producto_Precio_P
     FROM `venta` venta INNER JOIN `detalle_venta` detalle_venta ON venta.`Codigo_V` = detalle_venta.`Codigo_V` 
     INNER JOIN `producto` producto ON detalle_venta.`Codigo_P` = producto.`Codigo_P`");
```

tengo este error y no se como arreglarlo

Comment: Una duda, esas comillas simples que utilizas, no deberían ser de estas? ' y no así ´ o así `

Comment: Las comillas simples se pueden omitir. Yo lo que haría es cerrar el string en cada línea y concatenar con **+**. O mejor - usar `StringBuilder`

Comment: Como seria eso  explicame por favor